# Call script tag onerror manually from external script

Tags: javascript, onerror

I have the following script tag of an external (but self controlled javascript file):

```
<script async 
    src="//domain/test.js" 
    onerror="
        (function() {
            doSomething(); 
        })(); 
    ">
</script>
```

The script is not critical and a good fallback exists. I want to trigger my fallback:

- If `test.js` is unavailable (This works)
- In test.js code manually.

Is there a way to trigger the onerror event of a script tag in the script itself? Or is there another solution to solve this without repeating the onerror code?

Comment: `onerror` is only raised if the script fails to load.

Comment: @Amy Once it's assigned to an element attribute then it's just a function reference, which can be called freely from anywhere that can access that element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can modify the script tag at all then it's easy.  Give it an id and you can select it by that id and trigger anything attached to it.  Here's an example...

```js
document.querySelector("#script-tag").onerror();
```

```html
<script id="script-tag" onerror="(function() { alert('error!!!'); })()"></script>
```

If you can't modify the script tag then you could identify it by the very fact it has an `onerror` attribute...

```
document.querySelector("script[onerror]").onerror();
```

If you have more than one script with an `onerror` attribute then you can get all the scripts and parse them manually, looking for the filename.

```
document.querySelectorAll("script").forEach(function(script) {
    if (script.indexOf("test.js") != -1) {
        script.onerror();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that :) Now calling `document.currentScript.onerror();` (with querySelector for IE)

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)